# What is wrong with the SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, syntax-error

Every time I try to run this select statement I get told there is a syntax error. Can someone please help me figure out what the syntax error is?

```
SELECT 
ZERO_SALES.STORE_NUMBER,
COUNT( * ) AS COLUMN0001,
ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER 
FROM 
MM4R5LIB.ZERO_SALES ZERO_SALES,  
MM4R5LIB.INVMST INVMST,  
MM4R5LIB.OPORBK OPORBK,  
MM4R5LIB.TBLSTT TBLSTT,  
MM4R5LIB.TBLSTR TBLSTR 
WHERE 
ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER = INVMST.INUMBR
AND INVMST.INUMBR = OPORBK.INUMBR
AND ZERO_SALES.STORE_NUMBER = OPORBK.ISTORE
AND OPORBK.ISTORE = TBLSTT.STRNUM
AND TBLSTT.STRNUM = TBLSTR.STRNUM
AND ZERO_SALES.STORE_NUMBER = 6009
AND ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER =(233879, 659250, 240896)

GROUP BY 
ZERO_SALES.STORE_NUMBER,
ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER
```

I am trying to get a list of the number of occurrences for each SKU number for this particular store.

Comment: Use `IN` instead of `=`. That is: `ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER =(233879, 659250, 240896)` --> `ZERO_SALES.SKU_NUMBER IN (233879, 659250, 240896)`.

Comment: And also, it's highly recommended to use modern join syntax (`JOIN` clause), instead of the comma-separated syntax from the 80s.